# Change textarea length when post submit

Tags: php

I have set textarea value is

```
1
2
3
```

and when print to var_dump is

```
string(5) "a b c"
```

But, I try post submit. and let's take a $_POST value and print var_dump

```
string(7) "a b c"
```

I think the new line is problem.

How can i make the number of letters the same?

Comment: This _might_ be an issue with line break sequences differing between different operating systems. Unixoid systems use `\n`, whilst MS-Windows based systems use `\r\n`. Older Apple systems used `\n\r` :-) You could replace that using a regular expression.

Comment: thank you good info. i didn't know `\n\r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using trim () function to remove unnecessary symbols

[trim ()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Or consider this function

[str_replace ()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: The output examples do _not_ show any additional white space characters left and right of the printable characters...

Comment: I try `str_replace('\n', '', $value)`

But, i should `str_replace("\n", "", $value)` 

It was a matter of single quotes and double quotes.